# New to JSON in nodejs getting some errors

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, getjson, twitch

```
getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/Jonathan_x64', 
function(channel) {

    if (channel["stream"] == null) { 
        //do something

    } else {
        ////do something else 

    }
});
```

that is my current code but when i run it i get the following error

```
 if (channel["stream"] == null) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined
    at E:\my ultemet bot\index.js:10:16
    at Request._callback (E:\my ultemet bot\node_modules\get-JSON\lib\node.js:11:5)
    at Request.self.callback (E:\my ultemet bot\node_modules\request\request.js:200:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (E:\my ultemet bot\node_modules\request\request.js:1067:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\my ultemet bot\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

Comment: Have you checked module documentation? https://github.com/zeke/get-json - callback receives two arguments: error and response.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there isn't a built-in top level `getJSON()` function in Node so you must be using a custom function.

From the stack trace you've shared:

```
at Request._callback (E:\my ultemet bot\node_modules\get-JSON\lib\node.js:11:5)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... we learn that you are using an [NPM third-party module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-json). Once there, it's trivial to find the [documentation](https://github.com/zeke/get-json#usage):

```
var getJSON = require('get-json')

getJSON('http://api.listenparadise.org', function(error, response){

    error
    // undefined

    response.result
    // ["Beth Orton &mdash; Stolen Car",
    // "Jack White &mdash; Temporary Ground",
    // "I Am Kloot &mdash; Loch",
    // "Portishead &mdash; Glory Box"]

    response.ok
    // => true

})
```

It isn't real code but it's clear that the first callback argument is `error`, but you have this:

```
function(channel){}
```

Since (as the error message states) it's `undefined`, that means that the call is successful—it's just you aren't reading it correctly.

---

I've been peeking the module source code and it's actually not very impressive. It's basically a tiny wrapper for [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) that doesn't add much value.

Comment: so how exactly do i fix it?

Comment: Just define the callback function as the documentation explains. You don't need to use the first argument if you don't want but it must be there!